# How can I determine the reason for the mismatch between the value of this infinite continued fraction and the expected result?

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures, continued-fractions, machine-precision, ramanujan-summation

How can I determine the reason for the mismatch between the value of this infinite continued fraction and the expected result?
$$6.9431070487= \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}7- \frac{7}{129- \dfrac{4096}{761- \dfrac{177147}{\ddots- \dfrac{n^{10}+ 6n^{9}}{n^{5}+ \left ( n+ 1 \right )^{5}+ 6\left ( n+ 1 \right )^{4}}}}}$$
This is a conjecture got from [Ramanujan Machine](http://www.ramanujanmachine.com/) and $6.9431070487$ is also the expected result I am trying to compare to the value of the continued fraction. I hope to receive any relevant details or background information for help with.

Comment: I suppose that the "Ramanujan machine" is just a blind implementation of a computation of continued fractions, it computes in the given example a continued value for some "small $n$", something like $n=10$ or $n=20$, doing this with a high accuracy. The obtained value (or its inverse or so) is then passed to some LLL-algorithm, against a fixed list of zeta values (and related expressions), and in case of a match we have a "conjecture". In case of a missing match, the code delivers the computed value to some lower accuracy. In our case $6.9431070487$. This "conjecture" is false.

Comment: Just compute to a better accuracy. (The linked source does not provide in a clear manner the definition for the continued fraction.) It would be interesting to collect the proofs, and have a better understanding of their techniques - instead of search blindly for new relations... At any rate, the "machine" is an interesting device, although the name of the great mathematician is used not in his spirit.

Comment: @dan_fulea Copy that, sir.

Comment: You should be more specific about what result you are refering to, I couldn't find it in their official results page, then I noticed it is just random tweet on home page they generated (maybe even automatically). Their "official" results are slightly better (and tend to be accurate), plus they refer to famous constants, not random decimal point number... However don't take them for their word, I notified them few years ago about one of their result being known/proven with links, they acknowledged it (twice), yet the web still says "new and unproven", that much about their professionality...